# Как разделить текст на пары ключ:значение

Tags: javascript, split

Пользователь вводит текст в который примерно выглядит так:

"ASB - 21
ASBW - 32
ASDWAE - 345 "

Как правильно разделить на пары ключ значение. Если убрать пробелы, то получается:
ASB-21ASBW-32ASDWAE-345
Как правильно подобрать регулярное выражение для split?

Comment: что-то уже сами пробовали найти и решить. Может есть наброски кода? И по самому вопросу, до знака тире только лишь заглавные буквы? а после только цифры? или могут быть варианты?

Comment: До знака всегда буквы любого регистра, справа цифры.
Сам не смог ничего дельного отыскать около часу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сначала можно разделить пары ключ-значение по пробелам, которые не соседят с дефисом. Потом эти пары можно разделить на ключ и значение по дефису с пробелами. Если нужно, получившийся двумерный массив можно легко превратить в объект.

```js
const input = 'ASB - 21 ASBW - 32 ASDWAE - 345';

const pairs = input
  .split(/(?<!-)\s(?!-)/)
  .map(str => str.split(' - '));

console.log(pairs);

const object = Object.fromEntries(pairs);

console.log(object);
```

Если пробелы не обязательны, тогда можно немного усложнить:

```js
const input = 'ASB-21ASBW - 32 ASDWAE-345';

const pairs = input
  .split(/(?<=\d) *(?=[a=z])/i)
  .map(str => str.split(/ *- */));

console.log(pairs);

const object = Object.fromEntries(pairs);

console.log(object);
```

Comment: Спасибо, это великолепно. Чтобы таких глупых вопросов не возникало, не могли бы посоветовать где бы я мог набраться знаний с регулярками?

Comment: Например, тут: https://learn.javascript.ru/regular-expressions Если читаете на английском, лучше тогда английскую версию, она чаще обновляется и исправляется: https://javascript.info/regular-expressions

Comment: Не могли бы вы подсказать как можно грамотно учитывать случаи, когда каждая пара в input дается с окончанием символом новой строки или пробелом и символом новой строки

Comment: Если правильно понимаю, замените в первой регулярке пробел со звездочкой ' \*' на более универсальный знак пустого пространства: '\s*'.